# Node js SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier SQL update

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am following this Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYEC7ydDj4k learning the basics of node js with MySQL and I have typed the coded exactly as the video but I am getting the following error [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJaF6.png)

let sql = 'UPDATE employee SET name = '${newName}' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}'
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Node.js v17.5.0

```js
//update employee
app.get('/updateemployee/:id', (req,res) => {
    let newName = 'Updated name'
    let sql = 'UPDATE employee SET name = '${newName}' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}'
    let query = db.query(sql,err => {
        if(err {
            throw err
        }
        res.send('Employee Updated')
    })
})
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use variable substitution inside strings you need to use the backtick character ` and not quotes.

```
let sql = `UPDATE employee SET name = '${newName}' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`
```

Comment: Thank you very much !